# Flutter обновить widget по событию системы

Tags: android, flutter, dart

на flutter переехал недавно и не могу разобраться с банальной задачей. Суть такова: нужно обновить widget при событии системы. В документации доступно рассказано как это делается по событию от другого widget но как связать все это дело с системным событием?

Comment: Что подразумевается под `событию системы`?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно вы подразумеваете необходимость в написании плагина.
Давайте рассмотри пакет https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity
Он позволяет вам внутри вашего flutter приложения получать актуальный статус соединения wifi \ mobile network. 
Так же с его помощью вы можете подписываться на системное событие обновления статуса соединения.
Такого рода плагины необходимо писать под нативные платформы Java\Kotlin - Android, Objective-C\Swift - IOS. 
Для примера рассмотри именно Android реализацию плагина на Java:

Здесь вы можете увидеть как мы [подписываемся на системное изменение статуса соединения](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/connectivity/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/connectivity/ConnectivityPlugin.java#L54):

В этой строке мы можем увидеть [отправку результата](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/connectivity/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/connectivity/ConnectivityPlugin.java#L53) в код дарт

Здесь же, в коде самого дарта мы [подписываемся на это изменение](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/connectivity/lib/connectivity.dart#L59)

Более подробно о написании плагинов вы можете [почитать здесь](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)